# Python using a dictionary to map values of numpy column to another

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I'm having a small syntax issue that I'm not sure how to solve. I have a dictionary with some values like so:

```
tenancyMap = {
        "256": 13,
        "512": 6,
        "1024": 3,
        "2048": 1
    }
```

Then I have a Numpy dataframe with a column called "memory". Memory only can have the values of 256, 512, 1024, or 2048. I want to create a new column in the data frame called "MaxTenants" that maps each value in the "memory" column to the correct value in the tenancyMap dictionary.

I tried to do it like this:

```
sourceAll['maxTenants'] = tenancyMap[str(sourceAll['memory'])]
```

But that is not valid syntax. As I get this error:

```
f"{repr(type(self).__name__)} objects are mutable, "
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Is there any clean way to do this without having to loop through every row on the data frame?

Comment: `sourceAll['maxTenants'] = [tenancyMap[str(i)] for i in sourceAll['memory']]`?

Comment: Are we talking about numpy arrays or Pandas Series? For series: `sourceAll['maxTenants'] = sourceAll['memory'].astype(str).map(tenancyMap)`

Comment: **Numpy dataframe**??   A `dict` can only be indexed one key at a time.  `tenancyMap["512"]`.   As a general rule `dict` does not work well with `numpy`, or even `pandas`.   The mapping you seek to do has be performed one element at a time.

Comment: @hpaulj To be fair, Numpy's structured arrays are very similar to Pandas DataFrames. On the other note, I think Pandas' `.map` works pretty well. with `dict`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, looks like `Series.map` converts the `dict` to some other structure that more specialized and faster.  I haven't done any timings with that.

Comment: Yes did mean Pandas dataframe. Sorry about that! Quang Hoang's answer appears to be want I wanted! Thanks!